# Cleaned References and Broke Project

Tags: c#, reference, asp.net-mvc-5

So I am working in MVC5 EF6 Website and I decided to remove all the references that I am not using.  Over the course of development, there were quite a few.  As such I went to references and right clicked on the project and Remove Unused References.  For some reason this removed a whole lot of them that are being used.

Right now I am getting an error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.WebPages.Deployment, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

What I've done is created a new MVC5 EF6 project and added back in all the references that were in a base project.  Yet this still was not enough.  Furthermore when I run the project as debug, it never even gets to my controller.  I can't debug on any of my code to try and get a hint what is missing.  How would I go about figuring this one out?  I've looked at web config and it has the right reference to WebPages.  Not sure what else I can do to figure this out.

Comment: So you are still getting the error in your question at this moment after adding back all references that a default MVC5 EF6 project has? This looks like a compile time error? But you said you can run the project as debug, so does that mean this is a runtime error? Have you seen this answer and tried the steps listed? http://stackoverflow.com/a/26821774/1804496

Comment: @Zack I have seen similar answers and nothing has worked.  I've decided to stop wasting time on figuring out which reference is missing and I've created a new project and started importing files 1 by 1 in it so the references get put in.  The project is now working but it took a while to replace everything.  I did this because I could not figure out which reference it was missing and I am pressed on time.  Thanks for trying to help Zack