# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.WebPages.Deployment, Version=1.0.0.0

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I am creating sample application using entity framework in VS 2015. My application was build succeed. But when I run the application, I am getting following error.

Server Error in '/' Application.

Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.WebPages.Deployment, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.WebPages.Deployment, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'System.Web.WebPages.Deployment, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' could not be loaded.

In my web.config, the runtime tag like below.

```
runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
```

Comment: Have you checked ? [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24040591/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-web-webpages-deployment][1]

Comment: I checked above link and resolve my problem. Thank you.